# Website hosted on gitlab pages asks to sign in

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

My website [here](http://bsde1234.gitlab.io/msreenivasan) asking username and password. No error in console. Website built in jekyll. This starts now a days. Before I was able to deploy the same script. Is this related with any gitlab pages permission issue?

Comment: I do not understand where the issue is, can you explain it better?

Comment: check your project's access control settings: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#gitlab-pages-access-control-core-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this (from your gitlab repo) try going to Settings > General and scroll down to Visibility, project features, permissions. Now update "Pages access control" to "Everyone."